# select row where string dose not exist

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a timetable, where I add the staff if they are going to work in a specific week.
I want to show a list of staff that dose not work in the said week.

My table add a post for every week that someone is going to work, so how can I collect only the users that dose not going to work a specific week, without getting the posts that regards another week.

```
SELECT tblStaff.strName as staffName, tblWorktable.strName as workName 
FROM tblStaff, tblWorktable
WHERE tblWorktable.intWeek <> 9
ORDER BY tblStaff.strName ASC
```

This collects the users that aren't going to work week nr 9, but of course, it does also collect all the users that are going to work, lets say week nr 10 or 32, and I do not want any other information than about week nr 9.

Comment: This is a statement of work, but a question is missing. Where is the problem you are facing? Definitively, if `intWeek` is a numerical field then you should not use `'$week'` but `$week`. What else is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that if I use this query, I do not get any posts that got week nr 9, how ever, I do get all the other posts that dose not have nr 9, witch I do not want. I see now that this query is not a good example, i will edit the post.

Comment: There are a few issues here. What would you do when you have two people with the same name? Wouldn't it better to add `staffId` to your table? Also, what you can do is to use subselect - `WHERE staffId NOT IN ( SELECT staffId FROM Worktable WHERE intWeek = $week )` Note, however, that if your weeks are from 0..52 only then you will run into a problem in the next year.

Comment: I got the right data now. But I have not thought about next year. Thank you for that, I have to get that data in there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try with a query like this:

```
SELECT staffName 
FROM Worktable 
WHERE staffName NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT staffName FROM Worktable WHERE intWeek = '$week') 
ORDER BY staffName ASC
```

This way you are selecting all the staff that is not in the list of staff that worked that week.